# Create Combination of list of value in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, combinations

I have a 9 parameters of datatype `varchar(50)` in my SQL Server stored procedure. However, I know the number of items I have in my parameter only at runtime.

Let us say, for the sake of simplicity, my 9 parameter is F1 F2 F3,P1 P2, A1 A2 A3,null,null,null,null,null,null.

Now I need to generate all possible combinations as follows.

```
{F1 P1 A1}, {F1 P1 A2}, {F1 P1 A3}, {F1 P2 A1}, {F1 P2 A2}, {F1 P2 A3}, 
{F2 P1 A1}, {F2 P1 A2}, {F2 P1 A3}, {F2 P2 A1} {F2 P2 A2}, {F2 P2 A3}, 
{F3 P1 A1}, {F3 P1 A2}, {F3 P1 A3},{F3 P2 A1}, {F3 P2 A2}, {F3 P2 A3}
```

Can somebody please help with this?

Comment: `{F1, F2, F3}` ,`{P1, P2}` ... are single parameter!

Comment: No. First parameter is F1 F2 F3.Second parameter is P1 P2. Third Parameter is A1 A2 A3. Rest parameter are null. 
 you can use comma instead of space

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using split and cross join

Below is the code:

```
SELECT a1.value,a2.value,a3.value
FROM [Split]('F1,F2,F3',',') a1
CROSS JOIN [Split]('P1,P2',',') a2
CROSS JOIN [Split]('A1,A2,A3',',') a3;
```